# How to deserialize XML collection to dictionary in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

suppose I have the following XML:
    `<appSettings>
        <add key="key1" value="value1" />
        <add key="key2" value="value2" />
        <add key="key3" value="value3" />
        <add key="key4" value="value4" />
    </appSettings>`

and I would like to transform it to an object like:

`AppSettings["key1"] = "value1";
   AppSettings["key2"] = "value2";
   AppSettings["key3"] = "value3";`

and so forth …

I've looked it up on the internet and haven't found yet something  useful. Can someone help me out on this ?

Answer (score 6):

Easy.

```
var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var AppSettings = xd.Root.Elements("add")
    .ToDictionary(
        xe => xe.Attribute("key").Value,
        xe => xe.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: i am looking for using solution using XML deserialization and not LINQ like in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomXmlConfigForAspNet.aspx

Comment: @Yossi - I think you need to provide more information in your question. What I (and others) have presented is quite valid deserialization. I'm guessing you also want serialization and maybe more than just a dictionary-like object?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with LINQ quite easily:

```
XElement appSettings = (...); // Parse your XML and get the root Element.
var dict = appSettings.Elements().ToDictionary(el => el.Attribute("key"), el => el.Attribute("value"));
```

Comment: i am looking for using solution using XML deserialization and not LINQ like in codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomXmlConfigForAspNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse("<appSettings><add key=\"key1\" value=\"value1\" /> <add key=\"key2\" value=\"value2\" /> <add key=\"key3\" value=\"value3\" /> <add key=\"key4\" value=\"value4\" /> </appSettings>");
xml.Elements().First().Elements()
    .Select (x => new {  key = x.Attribute("key").Value, value = x.Attribute("value").Value })
    .ToDictionary(e => e.key, e => e.value).Dump();
```

Comment: i am looking for using solution using XML deserialization and not LINQ like in codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomXmlConfigForAspNet.aspx

Comment: Why don't you just right your own deserialization code then ? Just create a custom class inheriting from Dictionary and implement IXmlSerializable ?

Comment: You've got it. that's what am i trying to do and it wont' work :)